# bootstrap modal works in Chrome and Opera, but the html page is not loaded

Tags: google-chrome, opera, bootstrap-modal

I have looked and searched, but I cannot find a solution for loading a page in the modal from bootstrap. The code I use(from bootstrap docs) works with FF, IE and Safari only Chrome and Opera don't want to load, I get the modal window,but no page.

I checked the Chrome console and it said : Options file xxx.html Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin and XMLHttpRequest cannot load file xxx.html Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
I guess this is the same problem for Opera 12.

How do I change this Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. That I can test the modal on Chrome and Opera. I figured out that once the site is on the server there should not be a problem anymore.

Comment: Are you trying to load the HTML from a local file?

Comment: Yes, it is a local file.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing local files with XMLHttpRequest is highly restricted in most browsers, and with good reason. Some allow it when it is initiated from a local file, and some don't.

For Chrome there is a command-line argument you can use to disable web security, which should allow it to work.

> chrome.exe --disable-web-security

But I think you'll be better served in the long-run by using a local web server for development and testing rather forcing the browser to bypass security features.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, I 've tried it on Wamp to bypass security,but it didn't work.Could you tell where I put the command-line argument, coz I tried it in Chrome and the run command of Windows to no avail